# MessageKit problem when implement MessagesDataSouce

Tags: swift5

I have problem when I try to autocomplete on function currentSender() and messageForItem() in MessagesDataSource protocol (Messagekit library). after I fill these function then it suggest me to add protocol sub again

Comment: did you finally get yours working?

Comment: yes it's working right now.